Smooth aggregated data
I have data which is aggregated in 5-year bins and I want to estimate the yearly series. How do I estimate the series over single years, so that the five-year-sums are consistent with my original data, but the series is maximally smooth?
Assume this is the data.
df <- data.frame(age = seq(0, 90, 5), 
                 pop = c(50, 55, 55, 55, 60, 60, 65, 70, 70, 70, 
                         70, 65, 60, 55, 50, 40, 25, 15, 10)*100)

ggplot(df, aes(x = age, y = pop)) +
  geom_col(width = 5, just = 0)


EDIT:
I went with Thomas solution which gives me a nice approximation.

library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(age = seq(0, 95, 5), 
                 pop = c(50, 55, 55, 55, 60, 60, 65, 70, 70, 70, 
                         70, 65, 60, 55, 50, 40, 25, 15, 10, 0)*100)

finterp <- with(df, splinefun(age+2, pop, method = "monoH.FC"))
df_yearly <- data.frame(age = seq(0, 95)) %>% mutate(pop = finterp(age)/5)

df3 <- df_yearly%>%
  mutate(age = age - (age %% 5))%>%
  group_by(age)%>%
  summarise(pop = sum(pop))

ggplot(df, aes(x = age, y = pop)) +
  geom_col(width = 5, just = 0, aes(fill = "Original 5-year data"))+
  geom_line(data = df_yearly, aes(x = age, y = pop*5, color = "Single year estimate"))+
  geom_col(data = df3, aes(color = "5-year binned estimate"), width = 5, just = 0, fill = "transparent") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "blue")) +
  theme(legend.position = "top") + labs(color = "", fill = "")


I'm no mathematician, but looking at your data my gut feeling is that what you're asking for is impossible.

You should not edit your question to include an answer. If you used an answer provided by someone else, use the check mark to accept their answer. If you created your own solution, post as a separate answer below. The community can then vote on the answer they feel is best.

Probably you can try splinefun for spline interpolation (or if you prefer linear interpolation by approxfun) like below
finterp <- with(df, splinefun(age, pop, method = "monoH.FC"))

data.frame(age = seq(0, 90)) %>%
  mutate(pop = finterp(age)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(age, pop)) +
  geom_line()



Thanks, that doesn't respect the constraint "five-year-sums are consistent with my original". It overshoots and undershoots. Besides, I need the data - not just a viz.

@bgp2000 maybe the update interests you
